# Modal para editar una tabla y listar otra tabla en el mismo modal

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap, modal

Buenas tardes comunidad de stackoverflow , bueno me encuentro con problema a la hora de querer rellenar un modal bootsrap, normalmente cargo los datos de una tabla pasandole un ID el problema esta en que entre los datos que estoy cargando , hay datos de otra tabla que también quiero pero no puedo listarlos, en realidad no se como hacer otra consulta en mi archivo donde cargo los datos. 
Así va la cosa.

Este es mi modal para editar:

```
<div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Formulario para Editar un Hostname</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body" id="edit_hostname">

   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

con este boton recojo el id del campo que quiero editar :

```
<a type="button" name="view" value="editar" id="<?=$hostname->id;?>" title="Editar Area" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>    </a>
```

con ajax recibo el id y lo envia a mi archivo php que se encargara de editar el campo.

```
<script>
 $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){
  //$('#dataModal').modal();
  var id_hostname = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
   url:"core/app/modal/update_hostnames.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{id:id_hostname},
   success:function(data){
    $('#edit_hostname').html(data);
    $('#dataModal').modal('show');
   }
  });
 });
});  
</script>
```

mi archivo php update_hostname.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['id'])){
    //DB details
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbPassword = '';
    $dbName = 'soportemdi';

    //Create connection and select DB
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

    if ($db->connect_error) {
        die("Unable to connect database: " . $db->connect_error);
    }

    //get content from database
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * from hostname where id= {$_POST['id']}");

    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        $cmsData = $query->fetch_assoc();


         echo '<div class="table-responsive"> ' ;
         echo  '<form method="post" id="update_form" action="./?action=hostname&opt=upd">';
         echo '<label>Nombre del Hostname:</label> ';          
         echo '<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value ='.$cmsData['name'].' required class="form-control" style="width:300px" /> ';
         echo ' <br />';
         echo '<label>IP del Hostname:</label> ';          
         echo '<input type="text" name="ip" id="ip" value ='.$cmsData['ip'].' required class="form-control" style="width:300px" /> ';
         echo ' <br />';
         echo '<label>Usuario asignado al Hostname:</label> ';          
         echo '<input type="text" name="user" id="user" value ='.$cmsData['user'].' required class="form-control" style="width:300px" /> ';
         echo ' <br />';
         echo '<label>Area asignada al Hostname:</label>';
         echo '<select name="area_id" id="area_id" class="form-control" style="width:250px">';  
         echo '<option value="1">'.$cmsData['area_id'].'</option>';                                                              
         echo '</select>';
         echo '<br />  ';
         echo '<input  type="hidden" name="id" value='.$cmsData['id'].' >    ';
         echo ' <br />  ';
         echo ' <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Editar" class="btn btn-success" />';
         echo '</form></div>';

    }else{
        echo 'Content not found....';
    }
}else{
    echo 'Content not found....';
}
?>
```

lo que yo necesito conseguir , es listar de mi tabla areamdi todas las areas en este modal.. pero no logro como conseguir rellenar los datos de 2 tablas en este modal.. necesito un poco de ayuda porfavor.. como poder realizar 2 consultas en este modal. 
Mis 2 tablas son estas:

```
CREATE TABLE hostname (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,    
  ip varchar(255) NULL,  
  user varchar(255) NULL,
  area_id int(11) NOT NULL default 1, 
  FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES areamdi(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table areamdi(
    id int NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,    
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL unique,
    croquis_pdf varchar (50),    
    croquis_visio varchar (50),     
    piso int (3) not null, 
    edificio int(3) not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

quiero listar todas mis areas para poder editar el area, eso es lo que necesito.
muchas gracias de antemano